# why I m getting clang error when i run on Xcode 12?

Tags: ios, clang, objective-c-blocks, xcode12.5, ios11.3

I am facing clang error when I am trying to run the source in Xcode 12.5 But it is working fine in 11.4

```
In file included from :1: PrefixHeader.pch:15:2: fatal error: malformed or corrupted AST file: 'mismatched umbrella headers in submodule' #import <File/File.h> ^
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11 clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation) Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29) Target: x86_64-apple-ios10.0-simulator Thread model: posix InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script. clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11 clang: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).
```

Comment: Without more context it's hard to say, but you might want to try and clean your project files up by deleting the derived data.

Comment: tried by clearing derived data but still getting the same